# i have a problem loading the resources of the page

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am using php laravel, and I have a login page that works fine but the js files and css files are failing to load.

this is the links I created:

```
<script src="../Backend/vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
```

from the view, I need to go there times back to go to the backend folder and two times to stay inside of it.

the error in the console looks like this:

GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/Backend/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Are these files located in the `/public` folder? Because that is the only folder available to the web.

Comment: i am going to check right away, thank you

Comment: @Jerodev thank you for your help, i am going to chose this as a answer if you add it as one, thank you for your help, it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these files located in the `/public` folder? Because that is the only folder available to the web.
If not, you should probably move the files there.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the right way is this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
```

Here I have a js directory in the laravel's `public` folder. There I have a jquery.js file. The function `URL::asset()` produces the necessary url for you.